# The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Navigation.BaseUriHelper' threw an exception

Tags: c#, wpf, app-config

in VS2012, WPF project, after add connection string , got error

The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Application' threw an exception

The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Navigation.BaseUriHelper' threw an exception

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionstrings>
      <add connectionstring="Data Source=x.x.x.x; User Id=sa;Password=abc; Initial Catalog=hello;" name="ConString"/>
    </connectionstrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

connectionString  with a capital **S**

The same with `<connectionStrings>`. Capital **S**

XML is case-sensitive.